# Flashing custom recovery using DD with locked bootloader?

Tags: custom-roms, bootloader, bootloader-lock

So, I understand that you can flash a custom recovery using DD. I have done this on my Nexus 6p, with an unlocked bootloader.

My carrier is Verizon, which loves to lock down bootloaders. I have another phone, an HTC One M7, which has been branded by Verizon. I have gained temporary root access using Kingroot. I am wondering if maybe I could flash a TWRP build to `/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/recovery`. I am afraid that this will brick it though.

Even if it flashed and booted successfully, would it even work to flash a custom ROM?

Thanks for any helpful answers

Comment: If I remember correctly, that was one of the suggested ways in lower versions of TWRP recovery. Unfortunately I'm not really sure if that works under S-ON. I would say back things up just in case.

Comment: @AndyYan lol Its worthless to me anyway as its pretty hard to use without any custom ROM. Just trying to do this to maybe give it some worth